# How to make countdown time after 0 0 0 0 back to countdown again in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I just want to know how to make countdown after 0 0 0 0 its directly back to 23:59:59 so i have a problem when i try to create countdown function when its expired it will go to -0d -0h -0m -1s , -0d -0h -0m -2s but when i refresh it back to 23.59.58 , 23,59,57. i just want to know after clear interval it direcy go to 23.59.59 not -0d -0h -0m -0s . this is my script

countdown.js

```
function warTime2(countDownDate) {
  var countDownDate = new Date();
  countDownDate.setHours(14);
  countDownDate.setMinutes(0);
  countDownDate.setSeconds(0);

  var now = new Date();

  if (now.getHours() < countDownDate.getHours()) {
    countDownDate = countDownDate;
  } else if (countDownDate.getHours() <= now.getHours()) {
    countDownDate.setDate(countDownDate.getDate() + 1);
  }

  var x = setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date();

    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var hours = Math.floor(
      (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    if (hours < 10) {
      hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    document.getElementById("second_chip_war").innerHTML =
      "02:00 PM War Start in " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      let newDate = countDownDate + 8 * 3600 * 1000;
      warTime2(newDate);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Thank you, glad to hear if you want to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether `distance` is less than 0 when you first assign it, and if so, increase `countDownDate` by a day before recomputing distance and continuing the function:

```js
function warTime2(countDownDate) {
  var countDownDate = new Date();
  countDownDate.setHours(14);
  countDownDate.setMinutes(0);
  countDownDate.setSeconds(0);

  var now = new Date();
  if (now.getHours() < countDownDate.getHours()) {
    countDownDate = countDownDate;
  } else
  if (countDownDate.getHours() <= now.getHours()) {
    countDownDate.setDate(countDownDate.getDate() + 1);
  }

  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date();

    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    if (distance < 0) {
      // countdown complete, add a day to countDownDate and restart
      countDownDate.setDate(countDownDate.getDate() + 1);
      distance = countDownDate - now;
    }
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    if (hours < 10) {
      hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    document.getElementById("second_chip_war").innerHTML = "02:00 PM War Start in " + hours + ":" +
      minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }, 1000);
}

warTime2('2020-06-21');
```

```html
<div id="second_chip_war"></div>
```

Comment: yeahh thats why i confuded, i use setInterval, but its going to 0-0-0-0 .